# Remove a undefined portion of a string

Tags: java, filtering

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner nameText = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name ?");
    String text = nameText.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Hello " + text);
}
}
```

My question:
Let's imagine, that the user in this code enters one of the following:

- My name is Fred
- My name is Fred.
- Hi, My name is Fred.
- Hey, I am Fred!

Let's pretend for ease of use that those are the only possible responses.
I want to return only the word `fred`.

I feel like an if statement should be able to get the task done, 
something along the lines of:

If text contains the string `"Hi, my name is"` or `"My name is"` or `Hi, I'm fred` etc, delete that portion of the response and return only the unique word not contained in the if statements.

I apologize if this is rudimentary, but for some reason I cannot figure it out.

I want to be able to check against a limitless list of possible statements to filter out.

Comment: In case what I am saying doesnt make sense....
I want to be able to filter out all words except for a keyword, based on a dictionary of phrases that i personally define, so that there is a logical way to predict what could be typed.
For example. In video games with filtered content, someone says "ASS" the system returns "***". The system has a dictionary of words, ass is one of them, that are changed to ***. This seems so simple, it must be something I am overlooking or just not developed enough to know how to do.

Comment: Yes, "if myString contains oneOf(arrayOfPossibleThingsToFilterOut) then ..." if the answer to your question.

Comment: For those specific examples (and probably some more), you could always just take the last word of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling exactly those sentences, you could try to detect a common pattern and devise a Regular Expression to handle that [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). For example, in all your sentences, the name is the last word in the sentence. Also, the name is the only multi-character word that starts with a capital letter.

```
String[] tests = { 
        "My name is Fred",
        "My name is Fred.",
        "Hi, My name is Fred.",
        "Hey, I am Fred!",
};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]+)[^\\w]*$");
for (String test : tests) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output for all tests is `Fred`. Those rules should also apply to other variants of that input, although certainly not to all, but maybe you can come up with something even better.

Comment: Wow. That is even better!
Thanks guys this really helped. I wish I could give you both the answer but this one is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `replace()` method to replace the part of the String which you are uninterested in, example:

```
String[] replaceInResponse = new String[] { "Hey I am", "My name is" };

String response = "Hey I am mark";

for (String s : replaceInResponse) {
    if (response.contains(s)) {
        response = response.replace(s, "").trim();
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(response); // Prints `mark`
```

Comment: thank you. That is the answer i am looking for.
and also, thanks for such a quick reply.